# C# webBrowser.Document.GetElementByTagName index

Tags: c#

the C# webBrowser form object allows me to access links within a page by their html Tag name.

By storing all of the links of a page in a collection

```
HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
```

I can then cycle through them by their index and have the browser "click" on the link

```
links[i].InvokeMember("Click");
```

So, this index works with *int*, until this strange underhanded error pops, saying the value must be between 0 and -1 (-__-)

```
    private void executeExtraction()
    {
        HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
        try
        {
            isDone = false;
            Task find = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => links[i].InvokeMember("Click"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Print(e.ToString());
        }
        i++;
        toolStripTextBox1.Text = i.ToString();
    }
```

the "int i" is publicly declared outside this method

EDIT - Okay I found my problem...
it's a timer that is calling executeExtraction, so every tick, the HtmlElementCollection "links" gets created.
then a task takes links[i].InvokeMember("Click") on a new thread.
So, it had to do with the threading. the "links" list gets broken when it tries to access while an other thread is busy with it.

How do I solve this ?

thanks